# Featured Image metabox (postimagediv) doesn't appears when it should

Tags: post-thumbnails, multi-author

I'm using a plugin called Co-Authors Plus for managing guest authors in my website. However, when creating a new guest author, the Featured Image metabox (postimagediv) doesn't appears. I'm almost sure that it's not a problem with this specific plugin, as I've tried it in other Wordpress installation and the metabox did appear. I've already checked the Screen Options and it's not there. Also, when adding a normal post the Featured Image metabox do appear.

This is a screenshot from the non-working installation:
[image: Doesn't works]

And this is a screenshot from the working installation:
[image: Here it works]

Do you know what can be keeping this metabox from appearing? Maybe file permissions?

Comment: Disable all but the guest author plugin. Do you still have this problem? If so switch themes. How about now?

Comment: If you are working on a live site, make a database backup. That is always prudent. The risk should be minimal though.

Comment: Switching themes made the metabox appear! Why is that so? How can I fix it? Using other theme is not an option here :(

Comment: You need to dig around the theme code. Try looking for `remove_post_type_support`.